# Windows number key 4 doesn't work when pressing spacebar and W

Tags: windows, keyboard, windows-11

It sound weirdly specific, but the number key 4 (not the numpad) just does not respond when pressed if I'm holding down both <kbd>Space</kbd> and <kbd>W</kbd> key. All other keys work, and the <kbd>4</kbd> key works on its own, or with spacebar only, or with <kbd>W</kbd> key only.

For example: <kbd>W</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> works, <kbd>Space</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> works, <kbd>4</kbd> on its own works, <kbd>Space</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> (or any other number keys) also works. Just <kbd>Space</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> doesn't work.

Edit: I did further testing, turns out that <kbd>space</kbd> + (<kbd>Q</kbd> or <kbd>W</kbd> or <kbd>E</kbd> or <kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>S</kbd> or <kbd>D</kbd>) + <kbd>4</kbd> all doesn't work, so It must be ghosting. What threw me off was that, the spacebar was relatively far away from the six letter keys, and even though 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 are all close to the letter keys, only 4 was affected. I don't know if this should be marked duplicate, as from the linked question, it seemed that there is a max amount of keys that would be detected, which I don't think has much to do with this question.

Comment: Many duplicates of this question, but it is often called "ghosting" or "keyboard matrix ghosting" see, for example: ( https://superuser.com/questions/1445219/ )

Comment: @Yorik For my question it's only three keys, and all other combinations works as mentioned in the question, only space + w + 4 doesn't work. So no, that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @harrymc I believe I didn't. (Edit: the comment I replied to was asking if I installed any keyboard mapping software)

Comment: Why would you need to press two/three keys together in the expectancy that only one will win?

Comment: @harrymc well I found this problem when I started using number keys to play minecraft (I was pressing ctrl + w + space + 4 because I was sprinting and trying to switch slots). All other numbers keys work. I thought this only happens in-game, but I tested this outside of minecraft and the issue persists.

Comment: It probably has to do with the electrical wiring inside the keyboard.

Comment: @KirkKD What is the make and model of the keyboard you're using? Can you borrow a different keyboard to try with? The more expensive the keyboard, the higher the chance (without looking at the keyboard's specifications) that it will let you press more keys at the same time.

Comment: My keyboard is not that good, it came "free" with my pc, it's made by a company called skytech gaming. The model is k-1000. I don't have any other keyboards, but I will try on other laptops to see if it's the keyboard's or windows' problem.

Comment: @KirkKD It doesn't look like a *bad* keyboard. I can't find any instructions for it - maybe you could contact Skytech Gaming and ask if there is some key combination to enable n-key rollover, but as the problem keys are quite close to each other physically on the keyboard, it could well be that it is down to the way the keys are wired in a matrix.

Comment: After testing it does kind of seem like ghosting, updated the question.

Comment: It means that the keyboard does not support full n-key rollover.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your keyboard does not support n-key rollover.  Look for one that does.

> N-key rollover, referred to as NKRO, is a feature seen in many mechanical keyboards. It allows the user to press multiple keys at once, registering each key press individually. This is particularly useful for gamers who press simultaneous keys.
>
> What Does N-Key Rollover Do?
> If your keyboard features NKRO it means each key you press is registered separately. So, if you press three character keys at once in a text document, all characters will display on your screen.
>
> However, there can be limits to the number of keys you can press. This is represented by the “n” in n-key rollover being replaced with a number, e.g. 6-key rollover (6KRO).

From [howtogeek](https://www.howtogeek.com/789557/what-is-n-key-rollover-nkro/)

Another reference [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_rollover)

And here is a [review of keyboards that support this](https://graphicscardhub.com/mechanical-keyboard-wrist-rest/)

Answer (score -1):

This happened to me with a microsoft wireless keyboard 2000 where space, any key, and 4 didnt work together and its called keyboard ghosting. It stopped happening when I got a new keyboard because its different for every keyboard. The solution is to use a different keyboard or use the scroll wheel instead of numbers if its for games.

Comment: That isn't ghosting. Ghosting on a keyboard happens when you are pressing more keys simultaneously than the keyboard is capable of transmitting at a time. Some keyboards are designed with "n-key rollover" which means there is a higher than normal limit on the number of keys they can transmit at a time. When a key is ghosting, releasing keys that are pressed will allow the other keys to send their signal. If keys just stop working its just a broken keyboard and not ghosting.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1167526)